# Load a SharePoint list into a workflow variable?

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

I am trying to use a workflow to lookup data in a column in a list and then compare that data in another library column then update another column in the library based on if it equals eachother.

Example: If List1: OfficeNumber = Lib2: OfficeNumber then update Lib2: OfficeManager with data from List1: OfficeManager

I tried to use the lookup column but it doesnt work with drop-down menus which List1: OfficeManager is. I know I can create a huge string with all the OfficeNumbers in it and set that to a variable but I need something that I dont have to keep updating the workflow.

This seems like a easy task but it is exscaping me on how to do it and I have also searched and found nothing except create a huge string with all the data in it.

Comment: Some questions: are you looking for specific data? or if anything matches data in the other list? Also, what are you trying to do and why can't you do a lookup column to reference (maybe this doesn't apply, but it seems like it does)?

Comment: I am trying to take 2 columns in 2 different lists and if the data equals one another update another column. Since the column I am wanting to update is a drop-down I cant just use a lookup colomn because drop-downs are NOT a option with using a lookup column.